# pass a local variable to an click function

Tags: html, jquery, css, function, var

I want to pass a local variable from one function to another and I have tried some solutions but they didn't work because I have a click function, I need to put the variable first of all and I don't how to do it, also I declared the variable outside the function but if I use it outside of all the functions it doesn't has all its values or inside the function *resaltar* nothing appears, any help is welcome

```
    let children=$('div[class^="fila"], div[class^="pieceRow"]' ).children()
    var clase
    $(children).each(function getClass(){
         clase=$(this).attr('class')

    $(clase).on('click', function resaltar(){  

        if (clase==clase) {
            $(this).addClass('shadow')
        }
    })
})
```

this is the html code https://jsfiddle.net/qb5fwcus/

Comment: you may want to look into your spacing for the given code. as it sits you have some issues with brackets / function calls. Easiest way is to copy/paste the code in and then hit  use the code button in the editor to indent it correctly for formatting.

Comment: I edited  the code

Comment: TY for editing the code. what exactly is the code attempting to accomplish? You want for each child to .... do something, but I can't gleam what exactly.

Comment: Inside 'fila' I have multiples p tags and inside pieceRow I have multiple img's, in this code I wanted to get all of the classes, both p and img are paired by class name, when I get the class I have to click on any of the p or img and it and its pair have to highlight. Ask if you have any doubt

Comment: could you share some sample HTML?

Comment: here is a small example https://jsfiddle.net/qb5fwcus/

Comment: why are you adding numbers to the `pieceRow`?

Comment: Also please edit your question to include the HTML as in this case both the jQuery and HTML are necessary to provide an answer.

Comment: I add numbers to pieceRow because I have multiple rows, I place only one just to give an  idea of what I have

Comment: I'll try to get this answered later, but just as a heads up I will rewrite the html so that it works a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code :

```js
let children = $('div[class^="fila"], div[class^="pieceRow"]' ).children();

$(children).on('click', function(){
    var clase = $(this).attr('class');
    resaltar(clase);
})
    
function resaltar(clase){  
   $('.shadow').removeClass('shadow');
   $('.' + clase).addClass('shadow');
}
```

**Explanation :** You can not pass any value for the callback function for any event handler. Either it can be an anonymous function, or a function, not requiring any argument. However, you can achieve that, by making the callback function anonymous, and call any function from it. In this way, you can pass variables.

PS : Let me know if I got it wrong in any manner :)

Comment: thank you sooo much I achived what I wanted, I only had to add an if (clase == clase) to the add/remove class :)

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that you will be passing it to a pure JS function.

```js
function myFunc() {
   console.log("My function!");
}
```

In your 'click', you're calling the function ''resalter'', that you're also defining on the spot.

You want to call myFunc, so:

```js
$(clase).on('click', myFunc())
```

Now, myFunc is not expecting a variable. Let's just pass a variable:

```js
function myFunc(myVar) {
   console.log("Passing a variable of type: " + typeof myVar);
}
```

Now, you're only expected to pass this var in the function you're calling. Given the previous example I gave, we have:

```js
let x = 1; // our variable

$(clase).on('click', myFunc(x))
```

This way you're passing 'x' as a variable, of type integer. Use this code as inspiration to try and reach your goal. It is a bit hard to give a more exact answer, given that we don't know what variables have to be passed to what function and what the purpose is.

Good luck!

Comment: this won't fire on click, as the `myFunc` will be invoked immediately. your second value would require either use of `.bind` or for `myFunc` to return a function